# How would you optimize this short but very slow Python loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm switching from R to Python. Unfortunately, I found that while some structures run almost instantly in R, they take some seconds (and even minutes) in Python. Upon reading I found for loops are strongly discouraged in pandas, and other alternatives such as vectorization and apply are recommended.

In this sample code: From a column of values that are sorted from min to max, keep all the values that come first after a gap of length '200'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Let's create the sample data. It consists of a column with random sorted values, and an extra True/False column, where we will flag the values we want
series = np.random.uniform(1,1000000,100000)
test = [True]*100000
data = pd.DataFrame({'series' : series, 'test':test })
data.sort_values(by=['series'], inplace=True)

#Loop to get rid of the next values that fall within the '200' threshold after the first next valid value
for i in data['series']:
    if data.loc[data['series'] == i,'test'].item() == True:
        data.loc[(data['series'] > i) & (data['series'] <= i+200  ) ,'test' ] = False
#Finally, let's keep the first values after any'200' threshold             
data = data.loc[data['test']==True , 'series']
```

Is it possible to turn this into a function, vectorize, apply, or any other structure other than 'for' loop to make it run almost instantly?

Comment: For this sort of dynamic, `for` loop seems unavoidable.

Comment: Note, `.apply` in pandas is not really going to be faster than a loop, unless you are applying vectorized functions over the columns.

Comment: i believe the issue is `data['series'] == i`, which is an O(n) operation, and `data['series'] > i` and `data['series'] <= i+200` are also O(n).  So you have an outer loop (for i in data['series']) that will run O(n) times, and inside the loop you are doing an O(n) operation.  So your algorithm is O(n^2).  Since the size of your input is 100,000, you'll be doing approx 10^10 operations, which is intractable.

Comment: to add on to my above comment: I'm guessing the corresponding algorithm in R was just O(n) after sorting, so it probably ran much faster.  (the O(n) algorithm would be to iterate through all the indices `i` of the column, and to check the diff between the value at i and i+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my approach with a `while` loop:

```
head = 0
indexes = []
while head < len(data):
    thresh = data['series'].iloc[head] + 200
    indexes.append(head)
    head += 1
    while head < len(data) and data['series'].iloc[head] < thresh:
        head+=1

# output:
data = data.iloc[indexes]

# double check with your approach
set(data.loc[data['test']].index) == set(data.iloc[indexes].index)
# output: True
```

The above took 984ms while your approach took 56s.

Comment: This accomplished it. Thanks. I will try to use this structure for similar tasks. Unfortunately, my loops require lots of subsetting. And subsetting too much and appending data can be panfully slow. What advice would you give me?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple, one-pass algorithm using one loop over the series; no need for vectorisation or anything like that. It takes 33 milliseconds on my machine, so not "instantaneous", but blink and you'll miss it.

```py
def first_after_gap(series, gap=200):
    out = []
    last = float('-inf')
    for x in series:
        if x - last >= gap:
            out.append(x)
            last = x
    return out
```

Example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> series = sorted(np.random.uniform(1, 1000000, 100000))
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda: first_after_gap(series), number=1)
0.03264855599991279
```

Comment: IIUC, this is a little different from what OP expected. this just compares each element in the series with the previous element, which is totally vectorizable. Maybe putting `last = x` inside `if x - last >= gap`.

Comment: I'm sure it's vectorizable, I just meant that optimising it is not necessary because the simple implementation is performant enough (compared to "seconds or minutes"). What specifically is the difference in behaviour?

Comment: And what I was trying to say is that it is **not** what OP wants.

Comment: I got that, and I asked what specifically is the difference in behaviour? I see you edited your comment to suggest a change, though. I've edited the answer and updated the time measurement.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. Your approach is actually cleaner than mine. The difference is that one does not know ahead which values need to keep/compare to, hence one can’t vectorize this solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### `searchsorted`

You can find the next one without looping over all... sort of.
This should be ***quicker***.
As pointed out in the comments, quicker depends on the data.

Note that I use a similar approach as Quang because they are correct, you have to loop.  The difference is that I use `searchsorted` to find the next position at each position rather than looping over each position and evaluating whether I should add that position.

```
a = data.series.to_numpy()
head = 0
indexes = [head]
while head < len(data):
    head = a[head:].searchsorted(a[head] + 200) + head
    if -1 < head < len(data):
        indexes.append(head)

data.iloc[indexes]

              series  test
77193       5.663829  True
36166     210.829727  True
85730     413.206840  True
68686     613.849315  True
88026     819.096379  True
...              ...   ...
13863  999074.688286  True
31992  999276.058929  True
71844  999487.746496  True
84515  999690.104536  True
6029   999891.101087  True

[4761 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: searchsorted is O(log(n)), with the while loop it might not be faster than the plain linear loop. Really depends on the data.

Comment: What sort of data do you suppose would make this slower?  You've got me curious (-:

Comment: Maybe one where you have to add every position?

Comment: I was just about to say exactly the same :-).

Comment: I changed the threshold to `0.1` instead of (`200`) and it is still in favor of my method.  But I'm partially convinced by your point.  So now I'm going to waste too much time on this... thx (-:

Comment: Change data to `a=np.arange(len(data))`, which with `threshold=0.1` would keep all the records. This data confirms my point.